# Normal size clothed human

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am making some animation of clothed human.
Clothes simulation is strange when I am using normal size of human model. Even though the distance of cloth collision is the minimum value, there is a gap between cloth and human, as shown in the first picture. If the size of the models are large, they are OK, like the second picture. I don't want to scale it. Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add Collision in the physics properties this includes settings for interaction with Cloth and Soft Body - the Inner and Outer values.

[image: cloth collision settings]

These are typically in Blender Units (or whatever units you have your scene set to) so 0.02 Outer would relate to 2cm if 1BU = 1m. You therefore may need to review your collision settings for the scale. Also, always ensure you Apply Scale on your model and cloth objects.

Comment: Thanks, I get a good result when the outer and cloth collision distance are set to the minimum.